Recurring functions, Next JS 14
I am building an application using Next JS, React, Tailwind, Prisma and Postgresql. I need to run a function once per day to check the database and conditionally send an email out to my users. Next js acts as my frontend and backend (server actions). I've hit a bit of a rut researching how to do this most effectively. A couple of options appear to be Cron or AWS Lambda.
What would be the most effective way to implement recurring functions in Next JS 14?
Cron jobs, AWS Lambda. No results yet.
